# MySQL: WHERE only IF ANY ROWS

Tags: mysql

```
                ->and_where_open()
                    ->and_where('orders.status', '=', 'delivered')->or_where('orders.status', '=', 'new')
                ->and_where_close()
```

This is what I got:

```
SELECT deals.*, SUM(orders.total_count) AS revenue, SUM(orders.quantity) AS qty
                FROM deals
                LEFT JOIN users ON (users.id = deals.partner_id)
                LEFT JOIN orders ON (orders.deal_id = deals.id)
                WHERE (orders.status = 'delivered' OR orders.status = 'new')
                AND (title LIKE '%cake%'
                        OR title LIKE '%cake%'
                        OR description LIKE '%cake%'
                        )
                AND deals.seller_id = 123
                GROUP BY deals.ID
                ORDER BY ID DESC
                LIMIT 10
```

This works well if there are any orders and they have either status delivered or new.

I would like this query to show ALL deals, also those who dont have orders.

So: If there exists orders for this deal_id, then it should do the SUM() and check if orders.status is either delivered or new, otherwise it should now and still grab the deal. Instead this query exclude the deal row, which I instead would like to grab still.

How can this be done?

Comment: Which ORM are you using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, which would give you also records if there are not orders. However, because you use the orders table in your `WHERE` clause as well, you effectively built an INNER JOIN after all.

You can change that by moving the condition to the join as well, or add an addition to the where clause that also allows records where `orders.orderid` (or a similar, mandatory field) `is null`.

Demonstrating the first:

```
SELECT deals.*, SUM(orders.total_count) AS revenue, SUM(orders.quantity) AS qty
            FROM deals
            LEFT JOIN users ON (users.id = deals.partner_id)
            LEFT JOIN orders ON (orders.deal_id = deals.id) AND
             (orders.status = 'delivered' OR orders.status = 'new')
            WHERE
               (title LIKE '%cake%'
                OR title LIKE '%cake%'
                OR description LIKE '%cake%'
               )
            AND deals.seller_id = 123
            GROUP BY deals.ID
            ORDER BY ID DESC
            LIMIT 10
```

Demonstrating the second:

```
SELECT deals.*, SUM(orders.total_count) AS revenue, SUM(orders.quantity) AS qty
            FROM deals
            LEFT JOIN users ON (users.id = deals.partner_id)
            LEFT JOIN orders ON (orders.deal_id = deals.id)
            WHERE (
               orders.ID is null 
               or orders.status = 'delivered' 
               OR orders.status = 'new')
            AND (title LIKE '%cake%'
                    OR title LIKE '%cake%'
                    OR description LIKE '%cake%'
                    )
            AND deals.seller_id = 123
            GROUP BY deals.ID
            ORDER BY ID DESC
            LIMIT 10
```

I don't know which ORM you use, but I think the second will generally be easier to implement using ORM.

Btw, you order by `ID`, but without using an alias. It's not clear to me (not to MySQL) if that is users.ID, orders.ID or deals.ID.

Comment: How can this be done in Kohana framework? Sorry for not mentioning. I dont think i can do orders.ID is null in kohana (second solution) or the AND in the after the ON() (first solution)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Kohana ORM, but I think this can be done using `->or_where('order.ID', 'IS NOT', null)`. If you got an ID field, that is.

Comment: I tried with:      ->and_where_open()
      ->where('orders.ID', 'IS NOT', null)
      ->and_where_open()
       ->and_where('orders.status', '=', 'delivered')->or_where('orders.status', '=', 'new')
      ->and_where_close()
     ->and_where_close() no success :(

Comment: You wrote in comment IS NOT, but in the answer "IS NULL" ?

Comment: Any clue on why the above query build not work as it should?
Translated it should be WHERE (orders.ID IS NOT null AND (orders.status = 'delivered' OR orders.status = 'new')) ?

Comment: I think so. `and_where_open` will probably open a grouped condition. The `orders.ID` IS NULL should be part of this group. It isn't in the snipped you posted in the comment above. I think it should look like `and_where_open() ->where('orders.ID', 'IS NOT', null) -> or_where('orders.status', '=', 'delivered')->or_where('orders.status', '=', 'new') ->and_where_close()`. Like I said, I'm not quite familiar with Kohana ORM, but the *_open and *_close functions seem to suggest grouping.

Comment: I may have mixed up IS and IS NOT. The code is right, the condition should be `orders.ID IS NULL or ....`.

Comment: ->and_where_open()
       ->or_where('orders.ID', 'IS', null)
        ->or_where('orders.status', '=', 'delivered')
          ->or_where('orders.status', '=', 'new')
      ->and_where_close() did the work!!